# Python base class' implicit super() call

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Currently I am starting to revise my python's OOP knowledge. I stumbled upon `super()` definition, which suggests, that it provides a derived class with a set of instance variables and methods from a base class.

So I have this piece of code:

```py
class foo:
    bar = 5

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.x = a

    def spam(self):
        print(self.x)


class baz(foo):
    pass

b = baz(5)
b.spam()
```

And this executed with no `super()` calls, no errors, and printed out `5`.

Now when I add an `__init__` method to the derived class, like this:

```py
class foo:
    bar = 5

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.x = a

    def spam(self):
        print(self.x)


class baz(foo):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.b = a


b = baz(5)
b.spam()
```

the script gives me an error: `AttributeError: 'baz' object has no attribute 'x'`.

So this would suggest, that if my class has a default `__init__`, it also has an explicit `super()` call. I couldn't actually find any info confirming this, so I just wanted to ask if I am correct.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you don't define a method, then Python finds the definition from the nearest ancestor - that's the whole point of inheritance. If you *do* define it, it's up to you to call the super if you want to.

Comment: So when I have an empty derived class - it's the base class `__init__` that's called, not a "generated" derived class' `__init__` with a `super()` call?

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) help?

Comment: Well as far as I can tell, it says nothing about an empty derived class, I was just curious how it's implemented - does it implicitly call base class `__init__` or does it create its own `__init__` and then calls `super()`

Comment: You're missing the concept of method resolution order. If a method is called that is not defined, Python will work up through the MRO until it finds the definition. There is no code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you define the method `__init__` in your subclass `baz`, you are no longer using the one in the parent class `foo`. Then, when you call `b.spam()`, `x` does not exist because that is define in the `__init__` method of the parent class.

You can use the following to fix this if what you want is to call the `__init__` method of the parent class and also add your own logic:

```py
class baz(foo):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__(10) # you can pass any value you want to assign to x
        self.b = a

>>> b = baz(5)
>>> b.spam()
10
```

Comment: Yeah, now when I read about MRO in Python, I get the idea. Thanks!